# Thread 1: "UITableView dataSource returned a nil cell for row at index path: <NSIndexPath: 0xf8f6ae2994a56f07--Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new in swift .I am trying to run code from old tutorial from this [link](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-content-view/). I have successfully resolved the language compatibility issues according to compiler instruction. I have successfully run the program. On app loading it struck on

```
import UIKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
```

On line "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" application caught in thread not load app to display it view controller.

> Thread 1: "UITableView dataSource returned a nil cell for row at index
> path: <NSIndexPath: 0xf8f6ae2994a56f07> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}.
> Table view: <UITableView: 0x7ffae001e400; frame = (0 0; 414 736);
> clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray:
> 0x6000029dd050>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000027f0640>; contentOffset: {0,
> -64}; contentSize: {414, 2486}; adjustedContentInset: {64, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <Delicious.ArticleController: 0x7ffade5086b0>>,
> dataSource: <Delicious.ArticleController: 0x7ffade5086b0>"

How i can resolve this issue and execute the app successfully? From this [google drive link you can download my app with this issue only](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1piB_ywu6y-P7WUhd1qzdxl4qgDaTeT7n/view?usp=sharing)

Here is cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cellForRow: UITableViewCell!
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoverPhotoCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CoverPhotoTableViewCell
            
            if let imageName = currentArticle?.coverPhoto {
                cell.coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }
            
            cellForRow = cell
            
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainContentCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MainContentTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel.text = currentArticle?.title
            
            cell.contentLabel.textAlignment = .left
            if let text = currentArticle?.mainContent {
                cell.contentLabel.attributedText = attributedContentFromText(text: text)
            }
            
            cellForRow = cell
            
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubContentCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SubContentTableViewCell
            
            if let article = currentArticle {
                let subContent = article.subContents[indexPath.row - 2]
                
                if let width = subContent.photoWidth, let height = subContent.photoHeight {
                    let heightRatio = height / width
                    cell.subImageViewHeight.constant = screenWidth * heightRatio
                }
                
                if let imageName = subContent.photo {
                    cell.subImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
                }
                
                cell.subContentLabel.textAlignment = .left
                if let text = subContent.text {
                    cell.subContentLabel.attributedText = attributedContentFromText(text: text)
                }
                
            }
            
            cellForRow = cell
        }
        
        return cellForRow
    }
```

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint. At least it shows you the actual line where the error occurred (most likely in `cellForRowAt`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code. Most likely the function `cellforRow(at:)` will have your problem

Comment: @Paulw11 look i have edited my question and included the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: That function can't return `nil`, but I don't think this function is even being called because the signature isn't correct. It should be `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Are you using a UItableViewController?

Comment: The linked tutorial is 5 years old and the datasource methods are Swift 2 code. The evolution speed of Swift is very fast. Convert the code to the actual Swift version or look for a more contemporary tutorial.